# I have a problem of using sqrt function which is used in a C program

Tags: c, sqrt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, flag = 0;
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("%d is a prime number", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a prime number", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the `for` loop why is the `sqrt` function is used? Because for checking if the number `n` is a prime number, shouldn't we check till `n`?

Comment: Well, I'll delete it. I don't think there's a need to add a second answer. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

If `n` is evenly divisible by `i`, then both `i` and `n/i` are divisors. If `i` is greater than `sqrt(n)`, then `n/i` is smaller than `sqrt(n)`, ie: for any divisor `i > sqrt(n)` there is a divisor `j < sqrt(n)`. If `sqrt(n)` is an integer, then it is a divisor of `n`.

Hence it suffices to test integers up to and including `sqrt(n)`.

Note these issues:

- computing `sqrt(n)` at each iteration is wasteful and the compiler might not be smart enough to determine that the result is the same because `n` does not change. Computing the upper bound before the loop is advisable.
- on CPUs without fast floating point arithmetics, using a different test may be more efficient such as `i * i <= n` or `n / i >= i`.
- the program reports `0` and `1` as prime numbers.
- if the user enters a negative number, `sqrt(n)` returns `NaN`, conversion to `int` is undefined and may produce `0`, hence the test will fail and the number will be reported as prime.
- if the user types anything that is not a number, the behavior is undefined because `scanf()` will fail and `n` will remain uninitialized. You should test the return value of `scan()`, which will be `1` for a successful conversion and `0` for invalid input or `EOF` for end of file.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n, sq, i, flag = 0;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (i < 2) {
        /* reject 0, 1 and negative numbers */
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        sq = round(sqrt(n));
        for (i = 2; i <= sq; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d is a prime number\n", n);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many good points.  Good this answer rounds to avoid weak `sqrt()`.  Alternative to `sq = round(sqrt(n));` --> `sq = lround(sqrt(n));`.

Comment: `i * i <= n` overflows for primes near `INT_MAX`. `n / i >= i` does not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: that's true `i * i <= n` will overflow for a substantial number of cases. Since `n` is positive, one can write `(unsigned)i * i <= (unsigned)n` or simply use `unsigned` variables for this loop, but the division might be slower.

Comment: Good compilers see the nearby `n/i` and `n%i` and perform these sometimes expensive operations for the price of one.  Could use `div()`.  "simply use unsigned variables for this loop," will still leads to incorrect functionality for `n` near `UINT_MAX`.   I recommend a solution that does not involve other types as _other types_ involve portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

If a number is *not* a prime a prime factor of it will always be less than or equal to its square root. This is why we only check factors up to a number's square root.

Consider checking the number `59`. Its square root is (approximately) `7.68`. If we're incrementing up from `2`, we will only have to iterate from `2` to `7` to determine if this is a prime number, rather than from `2` to `59` (or rather `58`). This saves our loop *many* iterations.

Consider how that impacts a number like `7481`. We can iterate from `2` to `86` rather than from `2` to `7480` to find out that it's prime.

As the number you're checking gets bigger, this saves more and more computing time.